# How to fill the background image in a UIView without streching it

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to set the background image of a UIView with animated .gif's that I'm pulling form Giphy.

The problem I'm having is that the UIView is stretching the image. I want to fill the background so the height is 100% and have it centered. So left and right of the .gif would be cut off - but the image would be centered on the screen and not stretched.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdUlJ.jpg) a screenshot of what it looks like now.

You can see it's fills height correct but it's shrinking the width of the image to match the UIView dimensions making it look stretched.

Here is the code I have now:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.giphyBackground(Title: "dancing") { [weak self] (gifUrl) -> Void in
        let gifView = FLAnimatedImageView(frame: self!.giphy.frame)
        gifView.animatedImage = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: gifUrl)!)!)
        self?.view.insertSubview(gifView, aboveSubview: self!.giphy)
    }
}
```

Any ideas

Comment: You can try `gifView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill;` or `gifView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;`  see which one you like more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should set the content mode of `gifView` to `Aspect Fit`, doing so will not stretch the image and will fully fill at-least one of the length either horizontally/ vertically.

Try setting

```
gifView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

Also you can use `scale` `AspectFill` on `gifView` as

```
gifView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

`ScaleAspectFill` will fill the entire gifView's frame but will also maintain the aspect ratio, doing so your image won't look stretched but it could happen that content either horizontally or vertically will go outside the frame(which you can clip).

Comment: Awesome, thanks!! 

This is exactly what I needed:
`gifView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFil`

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely looking for the view's contentMode `ScaleAspectFit`. Simply add a line `gifView.contentMode=UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit`